# PhpMyAdmin Linux installation won't install

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have LAMP stack working perfectly, but whatever combination of passwords I choose in phpmyadmin installation (I choose both 100% correct and incorrect combos, both TCP/IP and socket option) this error constantly pops up and I can't find anyone else having the same problem. No third party source, everything via apt. Distro is Debian.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Elva, I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the proper place to ask this question.  This particular site is focused on answering programming questions.  You might have more luck over at Server Fault, which is essentially the system administration version of Stack Overflow.  Given that your problem is about installing particular software on your system, you might have better luck over there.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much @MajorProductions, always nice to learn something new :D